# global object for returning spring singletons

Tags: java, spring

Is there anything wrong from a design point of view with having a global object that returns singletons from the spring context?

I just started work at a new place, and the DAOs are all accessed via a global object called DAOUtils, where each DAO gets the singleton DAO bean from the spring context. So if you want to save a purchase order, for example, you would say

DAOUtils.getPurchaseOrderDao().savePurchaseOrder(po);

or something like that.

I've been used to injecting the DAOs as required into each class that needs them, and so this shocked me a little. Is there something wrong with it from a design point of view, and if so can you explain why it is a bad idea?

I can see that it makes unit testing difficult, because there's no way to stop the code from calling the actual DAOUtils class..? I guess that could be described as a problem caused by tight coupling?

Comment: You got it right. The guy designing this used Spring without understanding what dependency injection is all about.

Comment: The best rule is not to use static tool classes and not to use "new" for non-domain objects

Comment: Also read Clen Code. Creating a *Util class is a road to a mudball. You'll need to add any new DAO to the class. This Util class depends on every DAO which not very good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bad design pattern since you cannot substitute DAOUtils with something else e.g. for testing purposes.

Spring uses dependency injection and that's the best way to retrieve DAO instance.